# read 19000 bytes from java socket(TCP)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

this is my simplified code

```
sock.getOutputStream().write(buff); //send a readRequest
byte[] rbuff = new byte[19210]; //Answer has 19210 bytes of data
sock.getInputStream().read(rbuff);
```

In wireshark I see that it is splitted in a few tcp packages.
But shouldn't the read wait as long as 19210 byte have arrived?

I get the data, but from a certain position all bytes are 0. This is mostly the same position but varies a bit.

Any idea what I do wrong here?

Comment: The maximum packet size is defined by the value of the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of the local network. Typically this is around 1500 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply study the Javadoc for [`Inputstream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()):

> "Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer."

Meaning: `read()` does not wait until it has enough bytes to fill the buffer. It is already happy when it could fill **some** of the bytes. Thus you have to check the number that is returned; and loop until you collected all the bytes you need. In other words: don't provide a buffer of size 19K; use a smaller one; and "copy" over the bytes you received into another data structure.

Comment: Side note: you should feel happy to figure this early up. I remember, 15 years ago, when I wrote my first "huge" java application for my first job, it kept showing strange entries in our tables ... for 3, 4 months; like once a week or so. It took a lot of hard work ... to figure that my code wasn't checking the number returned by read; so in very rare situations, it would read only 3 bytes, instead of 5; and then all following steps "successfully" processed incomplete data ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to read it in chunks like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b= new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while (count = in.read(buf)) > 0)
{
  b.write(buf,0,n);
}

byte data[] = b.toByteArray();
```

Comment: @EJP:- Yes that is a better one!